# Android Studio - "Enable ADB integration" unchecked for no reason

Tags: android-studio

Since I installed the new studio version 1.2 and even more frequently since the last update to 1.2.1.1 the Tools->Andorid->Enable ADB integration option becomes unchecked without me doing anything.

I check it back and then one day later it is unchecked again - any idea what causes this?

Comment: Some other tools such as DDMS tool or device monitor also use Android Debug Bridge, and since only one of them can be connected at a time, maybe they are removing the check?

Comment: @mcy - I don't know. When I opened this issue it happened several times, but since then it didn't reproduce at all - I moved with the studio versions as they released and now I'm on 2.0 and I don't experience this issue.

Comment: I now experience this issue *after* upgrading to Android Studio 2.0.0. It is extremely annoying that my settings are not retained.